# Updating the XAP of a BETA app in Windows Phone marketplace

Tags: windows-phone-7, xap

Is that possible to update the xap file submitted for BETA version in Windows Phone Marketplace. Will the link changes if I update the xap file for the same. ?

Thanks,
Harl

Comment: +1 to the question. Had the strange behavior, when updated my beta once - the xap file remained old. Didn't get, how this happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can update the xap file for the BETA app. Click on your app name in your App dashboard page,and you will see the Update App link.

The link won't change after the Update. Link will be the same. And it takes 24 hours for the update process to complete.

Comment: Updating the XAP without changing the beta app is a good option. Thank you nkchandra for confirming on this.